# Digital versions of Greek Bibles

Tags: greek, manuscript

Does anyone know if there are digital versions of these greek New Testament texts available? Not just online or pdf versions, but complete downloadable full Greek texts in unicode text format:

1. Textus Sinaiticus
2. Textus Vaticanus
3. [Textus Receptus](http://unbound.biola.edu/index.cfm?method=downloads.showDownloadMain) ([Download](http://unbound.biola.edu/downloads/bibles/greek_tischendorf.zip?CFID=33385784&CFTOKEN=80815906?CFID=33385784&CFTOKEN=80815906))
4. [Westcott and Hort](http://unbound.biola.edu/index.cfm?method=downloads.showDownloadMain) ([Download](http://unbound.biola.edu/downloads/bibles/greek_WH_UBS4.zip?CFID=33385784&CFTOKEN=80815906?CFID=33385784&CFTOKEN=80815906))
5. Ivan Panin Greek New Testament edition

And maybe if you know any other good options for comparative studies, I'd appreciate.

I will add hyperlinks to the titles, when I have found pleasing site for my purpose with your help.

Comment: For Codex Sinaiticus, you can read it online [here](http://codexsinaiticus.org/en/manuscript.aspx). Others are rare, you might have to buy it from online shopping sites.

Comment: Your link for the TR is pointing to Tischendorf's text, which is very different from the TR and closer to the WH text. You're safer to go with Scrivener's text on the TR.

Comment: [What good reference works on Biblical studies are available (freely) online?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/639/) Check out 'Texts'.

Comment: I have looked unsuccessfully so far for a Greek unicode text of Panin's Greek New Testament. I have a photocopy pdf. And I can enter text in polytonic Greek from my computer keyboard rather quickly. This conversation spurs me on to continue to enter the text manually (attempts at OCR have failed so far). If anyone else is interested in helping out, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I did some Google search for you. I found these online resources. Some are Unicode, some are not.

1. [Codex Sinaiticus](http://codexsinaiticus.org/en/manuscript.aspx)
2. [Codex Vaticanus](https://archive.org/stream/CodexVaticanusbFacSimile/Codex-Vaticanus-NT#page/n0/mode/2up)
3. [Textus Receptus](http://www.scripture4all.org/OnlineInterlinear/Greek_Index.htm)
4. [Westcott and Hort](http://www.ccel.org/w/westcott/gnt/toc.htm)
5. [Ivan Panin Greek New Testament edition](http://www.scribd.com/doc/644433/Ivan-Panin-The-New-Testament-in-the-Original-Greek-)

Comment: None of these fits to my requirements except Westcott and Hort, but even on that case I would need to download all 66 books separately to my computer. Lot's of extra work :)

Comment: @PHPGAE Yup. These are expensive stuffs. Won't get it free of cost easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested there are two excellent free downloadable Bible study programs, both of which have numerous Bible versions for download including both Hebrew and Greek translations. They are http//www The word.org and http//www. e-sword.net. you can preview either one prior to downloading. I have both and find them extremely valuable. You also can compare translations side by side, and there are many other aids that can be downloaded to enhance each program. Something else that may be helpful if you wish to study Scripture is a program named what the Bible says you can download a free trial version, and if you like it it is very cheap to buy.